# Why do they use underscores in instance names?

Tags: flutter, dart

Many public example codes, pub plugin codes include classes and states with instances named with an underscore as a prefix. What's this about? Where did this fashion came from? Is it some popular programming pattern in Dart or just a matter of taste? :D

```
class State extends State<widget>{
  int _index = 1;
  _increment() => _index++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming from the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library.